# Wait for user mouse click in each while loop iteration

Tags: java, swing, chess

I am trying to build a chess game with a GUI interface using Java's Swing library. When I start the game, a window with the chess board opens.

What I'm stuck on, is that each time, I want to wait for the current player to make a move, and not run the while loop infinitely, since this is not very efficient.

Here's the code and explanation afterwards:

```
private void startGame()
{
    while (!board.terminalBoard())
    {
        Move movePlayed = null;

        // whilist making the move returns false, meaning we cant do it...
        while (canMakeMove(movePlayed))
        {
            // TODO: Implement the getting move here
        }
        
        // If move is okay, make it
        board.movePiece(movePlayed.getStart(), movePlayed.getEnd());
    
        // Repaint the chessboard
        chessboard.loadImages(board);
        chessboard.repaintBoard();

        currColor ^= Piece.BLACK;
    }
}
```

In the inner while loop, while the move the was played by the user is invalid, it iterates again and should wait for another move.
What I do not understand is how I can wait for the player to make a move.

In my case, a player can make a move by clicking 2 times on the board - source square and destination square. And then my function checks if it is valid.

How do I wait for the user to click 2 times on the Java Swing window?

---

Edited code:
The thing is, if i remove the thread.sleep like you said, the app does not respond to my clicks.

```
private void startGame()
    {
        while (!board.terminalBoard())
        {
            Move movePlayed = chessboard.getMove(board);

            // whilist making the move returns false, meaning we cant do it...
            if(canMakeMove(movePlayed))
            {
                // If move is okay, make it
                board.movePiece(movePlayed.getStart(), movePlayed.getEnd());
            
                // Repaint the chessboard
                chessboard.loadImages(board);
                chessboard.repaintBoard();

                currColor ^= Piece.BLACK;
            }

            /* try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're falling into a common trap for programmers who are new to creating event-driven programs: you're coding this as if it were a linear console program, for example one that uses Scanner based on System.in and println, using a while loop to allow the code to do repetitive action, when this will simply not work in GUI coding. Instead, you should wait for user input by listening for user *events* such as ActionListeners to listen for button presses, or MouseListeners for mouse actions, and you should remove the while loop. Instead of a while loop, base the program's response to the user's input on the ***state*** of the program, the values held by key state fields. The key paradigms to use are:

- Event-driven programming, and
- The State Design Pattern

So here, those fields could be something like:

- `private boolean whitesTurn;` -- if true listen for white to make moves. If false, ignore white's input
- `private ChessCell firstClick;` this could hold the cell that gets the first click. If null, then the player hasn't made a first click yet, but if it isn't null and holds a viable chess board cell (however your define it), then a first click has been made and the next click may be on the second location

For a example, please see the code below. Note however that for the sake of brevity, this example does not use M-V-C -- Model-View-Controller, which I do recommend that you use.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestChess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }

            private void createAndShowGUI() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Chess");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GameBoardPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
class GameBoardPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String WHITE = "WHITE";
    public static final String BLACK = "BLACK";
    public static final int ROWS = 8;
    public static final int COLS = 8;
    private JPanel[][] board = new JPanel[ROWS][COLS];
    private JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
    private JLabel whitePiece;
    private JLabel blackPiece;
    private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(WHITE);
    private boolean isWhiteTurn = true;
    private ChessCellPanel firstSelectedCell = null;

    public GameBoardPanel() {
        whitePiece = new JLabel(createIcon(new Color(240, 240, 240)));
        blackPiece = new JLabel(createIcon(new Color(20, 20, 20)));

        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                ChessCellPanel cellPanel = new ChessCellPanel(row, col);
                cellPanel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
                boardPanel.add(cellPanel);
                board[row][col] = cellPanel;
            }
        }

        addPiece(ROWS - 1, COLS - 1, whitePiece);
        addPiece(0, 0, blackPiece);

        JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
        statusPanel.add(new JLabel("Turn: "));
        statusPanel.add(statusLabel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(boardPanel);
        add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            ChessCellPanel cellPanel = (ChessCellPanel) e.getSource();
            if (cellPanel.getComponents().length > 0 && firstSelectedCell == null) {
                JLabel piece = (JLabel) cellPanel.getComponent(0);
                if (piece == (isWhiteTurn ? whitePiece : blackPiece)) {
                    firstSelectedCell = cellPanel;
                    cellPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            } else if (firstSelectedCell != null) {
                if (cellPanel == firstSelectedCell) {
                    firstSelectedCell.setBackground(cellPanel.getCellColor());
                    firstSelectedCell = null;
                } else {
                    cellPanel.removeAll();
                    cellPanel.add(firstSelectedCell.getComponent(0));
                    firstSelectedCell.removeAll();
                    firstSelectedCell.setBackground(firstSelectedCell.getCellColor());
                    firstSelectedCell = null;
                    isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn;
                    statusLabel.setText(isWhiteTurn ? WHITE : BLACK);
                }
                boardPanel.revalidate();
                boardPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addPiece(int i, int j, JLabel piece) {
        ChessCellPanel cellPanel = (ChessCellPanel) board[i][j];
        cellPanel.add(piece);
    }

    private Icon createIcon(Color color) {
        int width = ChessCellPanel.CELL_SIZE - 20;
        int height = ChessCellPanel.CELL_SIZE - 20;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillOval(4, 4, width - 8, height - 8);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawOval(4, 4, width - 8, height - 8);
        g2d.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

}
```

```
class ChessCellPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 100;
    private static final Color LIGHT_COLOR = new Color(240, 217, 181);
    private static final Color DARK_COLOR = new Color(181, 136, 99);
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private Color cellColor;

    public ChessCellPanel(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.cellColor = (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? LIGHT_COLOR : DARK_COLOR;
        setBackground(cellColor);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public Color getCellColor() {
        return cellColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
    }
}
```

---

The key to this example is in the MouseListener (actually a MouseAdapter) which does the following:

1. Gets the JPanel that was clicked
2. Checks

   - if the JPanel holds a component, a JLabel
   - also if the key state variable, `firstSelectedCell` is null, if no chess piece has been selected
3. If the cell holds a piece and first selected cell is null, then

   - checks the "color" of the piece and whose turn it is.
   - If color and turn match, it then sets the `firstSelectedCell` state field with this cell
   - Show that the cell has been selected (here set its background color)
4. Otherwise, if firstSelectedCell isn't null, then,

   - a chess piece has already been selected
   - this is now the *second* mouse press
5. If the cell for the second press is the same as the first press, oops
6. Otherwise we're good:

   - remove the chess piece from the first cell
   - move it to the second cell
   - reset firstSelectedCell to null
   - toggle `isWhiteTurn`
   - Change status label to show that it is white's turn
7. Tell the layout managers to re-layout components, and request that the chess board be re-painted

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    ChessCellPanel cellPanel = (ChessCellPanel) e.getSource(); //1
    
    // 2
    if (cellPanel.getComponents().length > 0 && firstSelectedCell == null) {
        // 3
        JLabel piece = (JLabel) cellPanel.getComponent(0);
        if (piece == (isWhiteTurn ? whitePiece : blackPiece)) {
            firstSelectedCell = cellPanel;
            cellPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    } else if (firstSelectedCell != null) {
        // 4
        if (cellPanel == firstSelectedCell) {
            // 5
            firstSelectedCell.setBackground(cellPanel.getCellColor());
            firstSelectedCell = null;
        } else {
            // 6
            cellPanel.removeAll();
            cellPanel.add(firstSelectedCell.getComponent(0));
            firstSelectedCell.removeAll();
            firstSelectedCell.setBackground(firstSelectedCell.getCellColor());
            firstSelectedCell = null;
            isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn;
            statusLabel.setText(isWhiteTurn ? WHITE : BLACK);
        }
        // 7
        boardPanel.revalidate();
        boardPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I tried that earlier but had some strange things happen, like i had to click multiple times for it to actually recognize the click.

Can it be due to an internal issue with the `mouseListener` and `mouseEvent`?

Comment: @nortain32: It is extremely unlikely that the bug that you're describing has its origin in Java itself. *Always* assume that the bug is in *your* code, until solidly proven otherwise.

Comment: @nortain32: although I will suggest that you avoid listening to mouseClicked and instead listen to mousePressed or mouseReleased. For mouseclicked to work, the mouse shouldn't move between press and release which can result in the issue that you're describing. This is not a problem for the other two methods of the MouseListener.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, maybe that's what's causing it.
Another thing - the click also seem to only work when in the inner while loop, i add a `Thread.sleep(1)`, to lower the times per second it runs.
Do you have any idea if it's related to the problem I described earlier?

Comment: @nortain32: Swing GUI code should not have and should *never* have a `Thread.sleep` within it. This type of code risks blocking the Swing event thread which will freeze the entire program, including all graphics, making it completely non-responsive. Re-think that code.

Comment: I updated the code and the question. Mind taking a look?

Comment: ??? @nortain32: you have not appeared to have made any changes based on my suggestions. You still have Thread.sleep, still have the while loop.

Comment: Yeah, I think I undertstood you wrong. Im updating now.

Comment: @nortain32: understand that you will likely need to almost completely re-write your program

Comment: Yeah, I see.
But what I still don't understand is why does it only work if I do `Thread.sleep(1)` (I changed to `mousePressed`.  When rewriting the program, I would need another way to do it, so I need to be able to answer this question first.

Comment: @nortain32: without the thread sleep, you have a "tight" while loop, one that completely hogs the CPU, that blocks the event thread, and prevents any Swing GUI interaction or drawing.

Comment: @nortain32: for example...

Comment: Amazing. You helped me a lot to understand it better. Thank you!

Comment: @Govind: nice try. I don't need to use ChatGPT since I only answer questions on subjects that I know and know well. I suggest that you do the same.

Comment: @Govind and if you want to direct your anger at someone, direct it at yourself for trying to pass of plagiarized content as your own.